# python Get excel sheet names in array, and put it in condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7

What I want is load excel sheet which is ("gx_projectid.xlsx") for my example. After then get the sheet names and put them in an array. After then if these sheet names ending with "_ID" I want to separate them. For this code they: [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[11] and I want to access and work on them later with "wb_obj.worksheets[x]".

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("gx_projectid.xlsx")  ## EXCELI YUKLEME
sheet = wb.active
Sheet_Names = [wb.sheetnames]
print("original sheet names:", Sheet_Names)


sheets = []
for row in Sheet_Names:
    for cell in row:
        sheets.append(cell.split())

print("Put it in an array : ",sheets)
```

my current output:

```
original sheet names: [['Reserved_ID', 'PowerLED_ID', 'RC_ID', 'Brand_ID', 'Product_ID', 'Panel', 'EDID', 'Cabinet', 'DEC', 'EnergyClass', 'CompatibleConfig', 'Project_ID', 'Project-id']]
Put it in an array :  [['Reserved_ID'], ['PowerLED_ID'], ['RC_ID'], ['Brand_ID'], ['Product_ID'], ['Panel'], ['EDID'], ['Cabinet'], ['DEC'], ['EnergyClass'], ['CompatibleConfig'], ['Project_ID'], ['Project-id']]
```

idk how to check if the sheet names ends with "_ID" because i tried:

```
for i in range (len(sheets)):
    print("sheet names",[i],": ",sheets[i])
    # if sheets[i].endswith("_ID']"):
```

and I got some error because its list not a string type.

Answer (score 0):

First a small tip, try to name your variables and functions with snake_case format. CamelCase naming format is mainly used for naming classes in python. I reccomend looking up pep8 documents.
Now let's get to the main problem. You are trying to use a str function on a list data type. First you should convert your data to str:

```
for i in range (len(sheets)):
    str_sheet_name = str(sheets[i]) # converting to str
    if str_sheet_name.endswith("_ID']"):
        print(str_sheet_name)
```

this should work. please let me know